# highstock mouseover out the left border of chart but there is still a bar data

Tags: highcharts

When mouse over out the left border of chart, there is still a bar to show, why?

First picture there is a bar outside of the chart. It looks strange:

[image: a bar outside of chart]

Second picture is the real first bar:

[image: real first bar show at the chart]

I want this behavior: When mouse at outside of chart I don't want to show any bar.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I want to upload picture,but there is a problem.so I add http link

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately tt is not possible, you can only disable mousetracking or hover option.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.states.hover

Comment: thanks for you suggestion,but I don't know why highstock do this,maybe if I know why,I can overwrite the highstock code.